# ServiceStack MockRequestContext CustomAuthUserSession

Tags: api, servicestack

I'm unit testing my API service and all is well using the MockRquestContext. The calls to this.GetSession() always returns an IAuthSession, but I have a custom AuthUserSession and as far as I can tell, there's no way to create an instance of my custom AuthUserSession and add it to the mock context. Is this possible?

```
var service = container.Resolve<AgencyCaseService>();
        service.SetResolver(new BasicResolver(container));

        var context = new MockRequestContext() { ResponseContentType = ContentType.Json };
        //Something like this
        MyCustomAuthSession session = new MyCustomAuthSession() { set some values}

        context.AuthSession = session//this doesn't exist but it's the type of thing i need to do

        service.RequestContext = context;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Session isn't on the Request Context, it requires a mixture of `ICacheClient`, SessionFeature and HttpRequest cookies to create.

You can look at the implementation for the way to [mock it inside a Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs#L129), which shows it first tries to resolve it in a Container:

```
private object userSession;
protected virtual TUserSession SessionAs<TUserSession>()
{
    if (userSession == null)
    {
        userSession = TryResolve<TUserSession>(); //Easier to mock
        if (userSession == null)
            userSession = Cache.SessionAs<TUserSession>(Request, Response);
    }
    return (TUserSession)userSession;
}
```

So to mock it you could just do:

```
container.Register(new MyCustomAuthSession() { /* set some values*/ });
```

Comment: I tried that but no dice. It's still an instance of AuthUserService, not my custom service (which is a sub-class of AuthUserSerivce). I'm calling this.GetSession() in my service and I can cast it to AuthUserService, but not to my custom sub-type.

Comment: @DonFitz can you show a stand-alone example I can run that shows the error and what you're trying to do? updating the question or in a gist is fine.

Comment: This answer is correct. I was accessing my AuthUserSession incorrectly using this.GetSession() as MyAuthUserSession instead of SessionAs<MyAuthUserSession>(); Thanks again, @mythz.